# Updating SQL Row if Records are same

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

In MySQL, I have a tblProjects like this -

```
Project_ID Field_ID     Record_ID Label
556895     1            1         Office desk 1
556895     1            2         Office desk 2
556895     2            1         This is a desk 1
556895     2            2         This is a desk 2
472246     1            1         Hello 1
472246     1            2         Hello 2
472246     2            1         This is a wooden desk 1
472246     2            2         This is a wooden desk 2
```

I use a sql query (written in PHP) which will insert a value like this -

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO Items (Project_ID, Field_ID, Record_ID, Label) VALUES ('232323', '3', '3', 'New Label')";
```

It's working correctly. But I need to Update the 'Label' if all three 'Project_ID', 'Field_ID' and 'Record_ID' are same - and Insert as a new record if any one is different.

As obvious from the record structure, Unique/Primary is not an option here.

Comment: You can make unique keys that span more than one column

Comment: @all - Thanks! it was my poor knowledge of sql with impression that 'unique' can be applied to one column only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. But before the function works properly, you need to enforce a unique key on the table.

In this case you need to have `UNIQUE` key on three columns,

```
ALTER TABLE Items ADD CONSTRAINT Items_uq 
UNIQUE (Project_ID, Field_ID, Record_ID)
```

and have this statement,

```
INSERT INTO Items (Project_ID, Field_ID, Record_ID, Label) 
VALUES ('232323', '3', '3', 'New Label')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   Label = 'New label'
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 5):

Why unique isn't an option? Just create it for this three fields together.

Then you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.